# Removing wp_create_nonce from code

Tags: wordpress

I am using a plugin that is likely giving me an error because of the usage of wp_create_nonce. Here is the code,

```
if($post['aramex_shipment_shipper_account_show'] == 1){
            $info = $this->getInfo(wp_create_nonce('aramex-shipment-check' . wp_get_current_user()->user_email));
        }else{
            $info = $this->getInfoCod(wp_create_nonce('aramex-shipment-check' . wp_get_current_user()->user_email));
        }
```

How can I remove`wp_create_nonce` from it without affecting the plugin functionality (but removing permissions)?

Comment: Which error do you get? You need to provide the error.

Comment: It says, "Äre you sure you want to do this?"

Comment: This is because you don't verify nonce at another side of the process. once you create a nonce with wp_create_nonce() you need to verify it at the place where it is needed:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce